# Console prints out the value but the value is not assignable to a variable?

Tags: asynchronous, typescript, console.log

```
    var a = "";
    Promise.all(aList).then(function(final) {

        for (let i in final) {
            var newbeet= final[i];
            a = newbeet;
            console.log(`a: ${a}`);
        }
});
```

The console will show a: "value of a", but in actuality, a is assigned to "" instead of  "value of a".  How to tackle this problem (probably caused by asynchronous?) properly? I tried using Promise.all as above, but still didn't manage to solve it.

Within the Promise.all that is used to extract the files from the zip, I have created an extra promise and Promise.all for it (<--The one shown above), so that the extra one can help me to extract the info from the html file from the zip. I don't know whether this is the valid way to extract html info.

Answer (score 0):

`a` won't be assigned to a value until the callback for `Promise.all` runs. If you have some code that depends on it, you need to not run it until `a` is assigned.

(If that doesn't help, I don't quite understand the problem)